# Data is not updating

Tags: mysql, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhKbM.png)

So unfortunetly my data is not updating even though I get a status request of 200 ok below are my front end and back end code

```
app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
  let update = req.body;
  mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET name = ?, thumnail_path = ?, description = ?, year_released = ?, language_released = ? WHERE idmovielist = ?",
 [update.name,update.thumnail_path,update.description,update.year_released,update.language_released,req.params.id],function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Above is my update query

```
$(function() {
  //Fill the list when the page loaded
  renderMovieList('movies');

  $("#movieAdded").click(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();

    let mydata = {
      idmovielist: $($("#newForm")[0].intNum).val(),
      name: $($("#newForm")[0].name).val(),
      thumnail_path: $($("#newForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
      description: $($("#newForm")[0].description).val(),
      year_released: $($("#newForm")[0].year_released).val(),
      language_released: $($("#newForm")[0].language_released).val(),
    }

    displayMovie(mydata);

    $("#newForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#newForm").toggle();
  });

  $("#updateMovie").on("click", function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();

    let data = {
      idmovielist: $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(),
      name: $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(),
      thumnail_path: $($("#updateForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
      description: $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(),
      year_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(),
      language_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(),
    }

    putMovie($($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(), data);

    $("#updateForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#updateForm").toggle();
  });

  $("body").on('click', '.editMovie', function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();

    getOneMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
  });

  $("body").on('click', '.deleteMovie', function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();

    deleteMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
  });

});

//FUNCTIONS PART----------------------------------------------

function renderMovieList() {
  alert('getList');
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      $('#movies').empty();
      $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
        const rowText = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\"  class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
        $("#movies").append(rowText);
      });
    }
  });
}

function getOneMovie(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist" + id,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(data._id);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(data.intNum);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(data.name);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(data.thumnail_path);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(data.description);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(data.year_released);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(data.language_released);
      $("#updateForm").show();
    }
  });
}

function displayMovie(mydata) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
    dataType: "json",
    data: mydata,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      renderMovieList();
    }
  });
}

function putMovie(data) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/updateMovie/2",
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      getOneMovie();
    }
  });
}

function deleteMovie(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/" + id,
    method: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

So basically I set my values in my update query to question marks so I can manually enter them in the UI I had put single quotation marks on the '?' but I was getting null values what can I do so that the info can be updated

Comment: Before accidentally writing your own ORM you may want to look at [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com) which can make this sort of routine code *way* simpler. You'll also want to consider using Promises and `async`/`await` instead of callback-driven code which can be dizzyingly complex to maintain.

Comment: Do any of your queries work? Are you seeing anything logged? Can you add logging to verify your queries are correct and that you're getting the right data?

Comment: @tadman I used post man and it was working their

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here. Can you trim this down to the code that's relevant to the question at hand? A single query with placeholder values would suffice. We don't need your whole app. As a note, it's extremely important to use placeholder values to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman ok so I added the querry relevent to the question

Comment: One thing that's worth doing with Node apps is building a test suite with something like [Mocha](https://mochajs.org) so you can verify this works before putting it into your Express code.

Comment: @tadman I mean it is not a back end issue it is more of a front end issue

Comment: Without tests you really don't know, you can only guess.

Comment: nvm I got it to work